# Set defaultSelectedKeys with a button click in antd Tree to change Selected Node

Tags: reactjs, antd

I would like to change the selected node in [antd Tree](https://ant.design/components/tree/) by using `defaultSelectedKeys` property, doesn't work. I also tried changing other property like `showLine` which **seem to work** but not `defaultSelectedKeys`.

Here is the link to code: [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/boring-wood-fmew4?from-embed)

Also, suggest if a better way to achieve the same.

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`defaultSelectedKeys` used only **on mount**, therefore changing the state without unmounting the component will not affect the `defaultSelectedKeys`.

If you want to control the select values, [use `selectedKeys`](https://ant.design/components/tree/):

> `selectedKeys` (Controlled) Specifies the keys of the selected treeNodes   | `string[]`